# How do I put a box with jquery inside a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, autosuggest

I am very new to javascript and trying to make a drop down box that selects the number of items you want to list. This works and when you choose the number of items you "want" it shows the right number of text boxes underneath. I want to be able to have a tag for every item, this would work fine however I want to be able to auto suggest tags. [This](http://remysharp.com/2007/12/28/jquery-tag-suggestion/) is the code I used to do it. I can't get it to work inside the function that shows the number of text boxes based on the drop down menu.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/ACkDpreF) is my source code and [this](http://spareslist.com/create_listing.php) is the link to my site.

I have tried using firebug and it says there are no errors with the javascript, the tag suggestion text box just doesn't do anything.

Thanks,
Cameron

Comment: you missed the link to your source code